# JQuery UI Accordion Not Expanding in Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui

So I got the Accordion function to work, but now it won't allow me to open or close any tabs.

http://www.azletconsulting.com/?page_id=13

Comment: take a look at the DevTools of your browser and you'll see there's an error loading `accordion.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

hi Baroti just change this css .. means add z-index to work fine

```
 .central_content_alt {
    height: 1400px;
    position: relative;
    top: 220px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```